# SQL how to identify records that get filtered out in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with ~1 million rows, on this table I have to run some filtering from 2 conditions. 2nd condition clause has to run on result from 1st filter. and at end I have to identify each row from original table if it gets filtered out by 1st condition Or 2nd condition or none (meets both condition and is in the final result set).

its like table.Column1 > data 1st condition
table.Column2 between x, y as 2nd condition

final result is 1st condition && 2nd Condition (rows with matches both condition)

What is the best way to mark rows getting filtered out in multiple where condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN <filter1_here> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FILTER1,
       CASE WHEN <filter2_here> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FILTER2
FROM TABLE
```

The result of this query is the same table with two new columns telling you if they are in filter1 or filter2.

How many,

```
SELECT SUM(filter1) as filter1_count, SUM(filter2) as filter2_count
FROM (
  SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN <filter1_here> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FILTER1,
       CASE WHEN <filter2_here> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FILTER2
  FROM TABLE
)X
```

Filtered data

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN <filter1_here> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FILTER1,
       CASE WHEN <filter2_here> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FILTER2
  FROM TABLE
)X
WHERE FILTER1 = 1 OR FILTER 2 = 1
```